# XMLWriter & recursion

Tags: powershell, recursion, xmlwriter

I have successfully implemented a Directory Structure to XML script, as shown here.

```
function GenerateLibraryMap ($path) {
    function ProcessChildNode { 
        param ( 
            $parentNode, 
            $childPath
        ) 
        $dirInfo = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::New($childPath)
        foreach ($directory in $dirInfo.GetDirectories()) {
            $childNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement('folder')
            $childNode.SetAttribute('name', $directory.Name) > $null
            $parentNode.AppendChild($childNode) > $null
            ProcessChildNode -parentNode:$childNode -childPath:"$childPath\$($directory.Name)"
        }
        foreach ($file in $dirInfo.GetFiles()) {
            $childNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement('file')
            $childNode.SetAttribute('name', $file.Name) > $null
            $childNode.SetAttribute('size', $file.Length) > $null
            $childNode.SetAttribute('hash', (Get-FileHash -Path:$file.FullName -Algorithm:MD5).Hash) > $null
            $parentNode.AppendChild($childNode) > $null
        }
    }

    $xmlDoc = [XML]::New()

    $xmlDoc.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction('xml', 'version="1.0"')) > $null
    $rootNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement('rootDirectory')
    $rootNode.SetAttribute('path', $path) > $null
    $xmlDoc.AppendChild($rootNode) > $null
    ProcessChildNode -parentNode:$rootNode -childPath:$path

    $xmlDoc.Save("$path\Tree.xml") > $null
    Write-Host "$path\Tree.xml"
}
Measure-Command {
    GenerateLibraryMap 'C:\assets\Revit\2020'
}
```

This works great, but takes upwards of 2 minutes on the file structure I am testing against, which is likely only 20% of my actual data. So I am looking at refactoring to use an XML Stream, as I understand that will likely be MUCH faster. I found this [reference](https://www.rogerdelph.com/creating-xml-documents-from-powershell/) to get me started, but it only includes the root node, and no mention of how generating a hierarchy works. It seems almost as if you need to keep track of the hierarchy so you can `.WriteEndElement` on each node appropriately. But that makes my simple recursion break down. I *THINK* I would need to simply `.WriteEndElement` after the `ProcessChildNode` at line 12, but I am not sure.

So, I guess I have two questions...

1: Before I go down this rabbit hole, is this going to result in noticeably faster code? Especially when dealing with thousands of files across scores of sub folders? And...

2: Can someone point me to a resource, or provide an example, of how to deal with the recursion issue? I have a feeling that is going to be a lot of banging my head on the wall otherwise.

OK, really three questions...

3: Once I have this working, I plan to refactor to a class, both for the performance boost and as an exercise since I am learning OOP. Are there any gotchas I need to look out for when I start down that next rabbit hole?

EDIT:
With Mathias's response, and some digging, I arrived at this.

```
function GenerateLibraryMap {
    param ( 
        [String]$path
    )
    function ProcessChildNode { 
        param ( 
            [String]$childPath
        ) 
        $dirInfo = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::New($childPath)

        foreach ($directory in $dirInfo.GetDirectories()) {
            $xmlDoc.WriteStartElement('folder')
            $xmlDoc.WriteAttributeString('name', $directory.Name)
            ProcessChildNode -childPath:"$childPath\$($directory.Name)"
        }
        foreach ($file in $dirInfo.GetFiles()) {
            $xmlDoc.WriteStartElement('file')
            $xmlDoc.WriteAttributeString('name', $file.Name)
            $xmlDoc.WriteAttributeString('size', $file.Length)
            $xmlDoc.WriteAttributeString('hash', (Get-FileHash -Path:$file.FullName -Algorithm:MD5).Hash)

            $xmlDoc.WriteEndElement()
        }

        $xmlDoc.WriteEndElement()
    }

    $mapFilePath = "$(Split-Path $path -parent)\Tree_Stream.xml"
    $xmlSettings = [System.XMl.XmlWriterSettings]::New()
    $fileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::New($mapFilePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Append, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write, [System.IO.FileShare]::Read)
    $streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::New($fileStream)
    $xmlSettings.Indent = $true
    $xmlSettings.IndentChars = '  '
    $xmlSettings.ConformanceLevel = 'Auto'
    $xmlDoc = [System.XMl.XmlTextWriter]::Create($fileStream, $xmlSettings)

    $xmlDoc.WriteStartDocument()
    $xmlDoc.WriteStartElement('rootDirectory')

    $xmlDoc.WriteAttributeString('path', $path)

    ProcessChildNode -childPath:$path

    $xmlDoc.WriteEndElement
    $xmlDoc.WriteEndDocument
    $xmlDoc.Finalize
    $xmlDoc.Flush
    $xmlDoc.Close()
    Write-Host $mapFilePath
}
CLS
Measure-Command {
    GenerateLibraryMap 'C:\assets\Revit\2020'
}
```

I tried it both with the `[System.IO.FileStream]` and instantiating `$xmlDoc` directly with the file path (still not 100% sure I understand the difference). In any case, all three approaches are within just a few seconds of each other, right around 2 minutes. So it seems in this case there's no meaningful difference. If anyone sees some opportunity to increase performance I am all ears, but for now I will move ahead with the refactor to classes.

EDIT #2: Well, I implemented the Class based approach like this...

```
class GenerateLibraryMap {
    # Properties
    [XML.XMLDocument]$XML = [XML]::New()
    [String]$MapFilePath

    # Constructor
    GenerateLibraryMap ([String]$path) {
        $this.MapFilePath = "$(Split-Path $path -parent)\Tree_Class.xml"

        $this.XML.AppendChild($this.XML.CreateProcessingInstruction('xml', 'version="1.0"')) > $null
        $rootNode = $this.XML.CreateElement('rootDirectory')
        $rootNode.SetAttribute('path', $path) > $null
        $this.XML.AppendChild($rootNode) > $null

        $this.ProcessChildNode($rootNode, $path)

        $this.XML.Save($this.MapFilePath)
    }

    # Method
    [Void] ProcessChildNode([XML.XMLElement]$parentNode, [String]$childPath) {
        $dirInfo = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::New($childPath)
        foreach ($directory in $dirInfo.GetDirectories()) {
            $childNode = $this.XML.CreateElement('folder')
            $childNode.SetAttribute('name', $directory.Name)
            $parentNode.AppendChild($childNode)
            $this.ProcessChildNode($childNode, "$childPath\$($directory.Name)")
        }
        foreach ($file in $dirInfo.GetFiles()) {
            $childNode = $this.XML.CreateElement('file')
            $childNode.SetAttribute('name', $file.Name)
            $childNode.SetAttribute('size', $file.Length)
            $childNode.SetAttribute('hash', (Get-FileHash -Path:$file.FullName -Algorithm:MD5).Hash)
            $parentNode.AppendChild($childNode)
        }
    }

}


Measure-Command {
    $xml = [GenerateLibraryMap]::New('C:\assets\Revit\2020')
}

Write-Host "$($xml.MapFilePath)"
```

Takes EXACTLY the same amount of time. But, educational in any case. It does look like the Stream based version is slightly more memory efficient. Hopefully someone finds the results useful.

Comment: It's best to ask one question at a time. See on meta [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this going to result in noticeably faster code?

Maybe. The easiest way of finding out (without actually profiling your current approach) is to just go ahead and do it, then compare the results :)

> how to deal with the recursion issue?

Easy!

Follow this rule:

- The recursive function call that opens a node should also be responsible for closing it - in other words, your recursive function should be structured like (pseudocode):

```
function Recurse
{
    WriteStartElement
    if($shouldRecurse){
      Recurse
    }
    WriteEndElement
}
```

As long as you stick to this form, you'll be fine.

> I plan to refactor to a class, both for the performance boost and as an exercise since I am learning OOP. Are there any gotchas I need to look out for when I start down that next rabbit hole?

Probably, yes?

Again, the easiest way find out is to go ahead and just do it - StackOverflow is still gonna be here if and when you bump into a wall :)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Your info on recursion got me going on the basic structure. And some Google-Fu got some other questions answered about formatting. So, revised version in the OP, but gist of it is, no meaningful performance difference. :(

Comment: It also occurs to me that the stream approach was faster in PS2, and the native PowerShell option has just been optimized in PS5.1 so now it has performance parity. I have seen that in a number of places.

Comment: @Gordon How many files are we talking about? I get a pretty stable ~20% improvement in execution time when using `XmlWriter` instead of appending directly to an `XmlDocument` across folder hierarchies ~4 levels deep with a few thousand files.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Currently I am testing against a little over 8,000 files, and at least 5 levels deep. But I am also testing on a VM (Parallels Desktop running on an iMac Pro) so I may be obscuring some benefits with my test environment. I'll have to try it in BootCamp and see if things are different there.

Comment: @Gordon Here's [the code](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/06761683ba313e5c48f548d011f75549) I'm getting ~20% improvement with if you wanna try it on. Make sure you do a cold run with each (to avoid jitter/overhead from a cold file system cache + initial runtime memory acquisition), before actually measuring/profiling.